# How to close an activity correctly with all threads?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

How to close an activity correctly with all cords?

I have an activity that uses multiple synchronous and asynchronous threads and end with and ended with "finish ()". But still open because some listeners (eg call) are listening.

A simple example is the following code:

```
...
test=new Timer();
    test.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    // @Override
    public void run(){
    countTime++;
    System.out.println("time es -> " + countTime);
    }
},1,1000);
...
```

I make a **MainScreen.this.finish()** and does not appear visually, but the meter still running.

How I can end the activity at all?

Answer (score 0):

Call `cancel()` on your `Timer` in `onDestroy()` of the activity. Or, call `cancel()` on your `Timer` sooner than that (e.g., `onPause()`). Your use of your `Timer` needs to be intelligently tied to the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks! But In my app there are many threads that are created automatically. Is it possible to end the activity with all the threads at once (without knowing the name of the object)?

Comment: @ephramd: "Is it possible to end the activity with all the threads at once (without knowing the name of the object)?" -- no, because activities do not have threads. If the thread is running (i.e., not blocked waiting on something), then *you* did something to cause the thread to run, and *you* need to do something to stop the thread from running. Or, find a way to avoid the thread entirely, such as switching away from `Timer` and using `postDelayed()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the thread in the onStop() (or onPause()) method of your activity by using mThread.join(). 
This could look like this:

```
Thread mThread;
boolean isRunning;

@Override
public void onStop(){
    isRunning = false;
    try {
        mThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you have a lot of threads to stop, you could store them in some kind of a list and iterate through this list and join() each thread.

Comment: Then he has to call cancel() on the timer in a similar fashion.